# How do I make a sell script? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, scripting, game-development, roblox

I have been making a Roblox simulator as a side project to learn how to make games, Now I have gotten some help as you can see below but it is still not working. I have got some pictures and videos in these links:
https://flickr.com/photos/195497771@N05
https://vimeo.com/user173767075

Currently my issue is still the title of my question and my tool not working. I changed it to a remote event and now it stopped changing my leaderstats. I have tried a bunch of different solutions but none work. My first script is my tool script. Here it is:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    if player.Debounce.Value == false then
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Power:FireServer(script.Parent.Values)
    
local action = script.Parent.Parent.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Animation)
        
        action:Play()
    end
end)
```

Now, that is in a LocalScript and that works. It prints that it activated and the animation plays. Now my problem is with a script in ServerScriptService not receiving the remote event. I have a print in it but nothing happens. Here is that script:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Power.OnServerEvent:Connct(function(player, valueFolder)
    if player.Debounce.Value == false then
        player.leaderstats.Sticks.Value += valueFolder.Power.Value
        player.Debounce.Value = true
        wait(valueFolder.Cooldown.Value)
        player.Debounce.Value = false
    end
end)
```

So, for my original question, the sell knows I touch it and it activates the event but nothing changes in the leaderstats. Here is my script to detect when the player touches the sell part.

```
local sellevent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Sell

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        print("sell fired")
        sellevent:Fire()
    end
end)
```

That script works. But that is a server script. Let me know if I should change it to a LocalScript. Now, here is my script that changes the leaderstats, it detects the the event fired but nothing changes in leaderstats.

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Sell.Event:Connect(function(player)
    print("bindable event fired")
    if player ~= nil then
        if player.leaderstats.Sticks.Value > 0 then
            player.leaderstats.Cash.Value += player.leaderstats.Sticks.Value
            player.leaderstats.Sticks.Value = 0
        end
    end
end)
```

I gave as much information as I could. If you need anything else I can get more pictures or videos but that is the best I could give. Any help appreciated!

Comment: In the ServerScriptService script, is `ReplicatedStorage` defined as `game.ReplicatedStorage` anywhere? Also, since you're not seeing any errors in the output, have you tried putting print statements into your Scripts to verify that the scripts are properly enabled and running as expected?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that there was no ReplicatedStorage variable. I will add that or do game.ReplicatedStorage

Comment: I added a print(player) in the touched script and a print("Event Fired") in the server script and the event is getting fired but the cash is not changing.

Comment: When you say the event is getting fired, do you mean the Touched event or the BindableEvent is firing? So you know that the player variable exists and is not null, that's good. I see you are adding `Power.Value * 2`, have you logged what its value is before resetting it? Is Power.Value greater than 0, because it would be silly if you we're accidentally adding 0? For debugging, you could try simply adding one to make sure that the values are actually changing properly.

Comment: I just noticed I was using the wrong variable. I changed power to sticks and never noticed that it still said power.

Comment: So, I changed my scripts up and they are still not working. I took some screenshots and videos so you can see more of what is happening. You can find the pictures here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/195497771@N05/? And here is the video: https://vimeo.com/user173767075 This should give you more info to whats actually happening

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you've got a nasty script in a cloud somewhere that's dynamically loading some code libraries. You might want to find it and remove it.

Comment: Should I change the BindablEvent to a RemoteEvent and the script in the part to a local script so I can do :FireServer()?

Comment: You should update your question to include the code that changes the Sticks values.

Comment: I edited the post adding more info to my current problems and scripts.

Comment: In the latest code, you have a typo in the script that receives the RemoteEvent. `game.ReplicatedStorage.Power.OnServerEvent:Connct(`. You misspelled Connect.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I never noticed it. Now time to work out the sell then we can finally finish up

Comment: Ok, so the sell event is getting fired but the leaderstats are not changing. It looks like we are getting close to the problem but not quite there yet

Comment: Once again, are you sure that you are actually adding anything? You are pulling values out of ValuesFolder and adding them to Sticks. Have you tried printing out what those values are before adding them? You need to take some time and actually figure out what isn't working. Try putting print statements on every line and see where they stop. Try printing out the values before and after adding things to them. Look at the Output widget and see if there are errors coming from these scripts.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the problem is on the if player ~= nil then line. I put a bunch of print statements in and for the sell the event is getting fired but after the if player ~= nil then line it doesn't print anything else. The values from valueFolder are there because I made it print their value and power is 1 and cooldown is 0.75.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've edited my answer to address this latest issue. Gj hunting down the problematic line.

Comment: That was it! It finally works and I can get back into my game. Thanks a lot for your help. I was close at the beginning and all I needed was a remote event for the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after watching the video, I might have a hunch as to what's going wrong.
The code in your original question works just fine. If you were to print out the `Sticks.Value` before adding it to `Cash.Value`, you'd see that `Sticks.Value` stays at 0. And you were always adding 0 to Cash.

This is likely because you are using a Tool to increment `Sticks.Value`, and it is common for Tools to use LocalScripts to hook up logic. When you make changes to the world (or `leaderstats` values) in LocalScripts, those changes are only present on *that* client. They are not replicated up to the server. And since all of your cash logic is in server scripts, the Sticks value stays at 0 on the server.

So to fix this, you need to make sure that the code that increments `Sticks.Value` happens in a Script. And you can do that by using [RemoteEvents](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events) in the same way you're using your BindableEvent, to communicate from the tool up to a server script.

So in your Tool's LocalScript you'd do something like this :

```
-- find the RemoteEvent saved in ReplicatedStorage
local stickEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.GetSticksEvent

-- listen for when the Tool is used
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    -- tell the server to give us some sticks...
    stickEvent:FireServer()
end)
```

Then, in a server Script, listen for that RemoteEvent to fire to give the player some sticks :

```
-- find the RemoteEvent saved in ReplicatedStorage
local stickEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.GetSticksEvent

-- listen for when the client tells us that they got some sticks
stickEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    -- give the player some sticks
    player.leaderstats.Sticks.Value += 1
end)
```

---

Edit - in this most recent version, your Sell script has stopped working because the player argument is nil. In an earlier version of this code, the Touched script passed in the player, but you removed that code and broke the Sell script. So just rollback the script to its earlier state :

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    
        game.ReplicatedStorage.BindableEvents.Sell:Fire(player)
    end
end)
```